# When i change the datasource on My datagrid the columns dont autofill unless i order a column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

I have a DataGrid on a Win Form that display perfectly when I initially set the datasource. The AutoSizeColumnsMode is "DisplayCells". When I change the datasource during runtime the rows do not autosize unless I re-order a column.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Also note that the DataGrid is on a different Tab than the button that calls the update.

The only code that I ever use to populate the grid is:

```
dgUnPrinted.DataSource = TableName;
dgUnPrinted.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking I decided to sort a column through code. This filled out all the cells. I am not sure why this is needed or why it works when everything else does not work but at least i have a fix.

```
dgUnPrinted.Sort(dgUnPrinted.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AutoResizeDataGrid.aspx
or 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoIAutomaticallySizeAutosizeColumnsInAWinFormsDataGrid.aspx

or use DataGridView then you can play with gdv.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode property.

Comment: Thats some really old information. .NET 2.0 has built in methods which i am using to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `AutoResizeColumns` method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158595%28v=VS.90%29.aspx